# 500 (Internal Server Error) Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

Пробую AJAX в Laravel, но почему то выдаёт ошибку 500 при отправки AJAX Запроса.

Шаблон страницы -

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        * {
            font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
        }
    </style>
    @yield('css')
    <title>@yield('title')</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark rounded-bottom shadow bg-primary">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ route('home') }}">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('projects') }}">Projects</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('about') }}">About</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            @if (Auth::check())
                <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" method="post" action="admin/logout">
                    @csrf
                    <button class="btn" type="submit">Logout</button>
                </form>
            @endif
        </div>
    </nav>
    @yield('content')
</div>
<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
@yield('scripts')
</body>
</html>
```

А вот сама страница на которой происходит AJAX запрос -

```html
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title')
    Home - jolyPage
@endsection
@section('css')
    <style>
        .bg-gradient {
            background: rgb(63, 94, 251);
            background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(63, 94, 251, 1) 0%, rgba(252, 70, 107, 1) 100%);
        }
    </style>

@endsection
@section('content')
    <div class="jumbotron rounded-lg bg-gradient text-white mt-5 shadow-lg ">
        <h1 class="display-4">Hello, world!</h1>
        <p class="lead">This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling extra attention to
            featured content or information.</p>
        <hr class="my-4">
        <p>It uses utility classes for typography and spacing to space content out within the larger container.</p>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-primary text-white bg-danger btn-lg shadow" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a>
        @if (Auth::check())
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Edit</a>
        @endif
    </div>
    <hr class="bg-danger"/>
    <h1 class="text-center bg-gradient text-white shadow rounded">News</h1>
    @if(Auth::check())
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-block btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
            Add
        </button>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade shadow" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
             aria-hidden="true">
            <form method="post" id="pochemu_ne_rabotaet_to">
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New article</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <span class="input-group-text" id="title_area">Title</span>
                                </div>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control"
                                       aria-describedby="title_area" name="title" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">Body</span>
                                </div>
                                <textarea class="form-control" aria-label="Username"
                                          aria-describedby="basic-addon1" name="body" required></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-submit">Add new article</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    @endif
    @foreach($articles as $article)
        <div class="card shadow rounded" style="width: 18rem;">
            {{--            <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">--}}
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">{{ $article->title }}</h5>
                <p class="card-text">{{ $article->body }}</p>
                @if (Auth::check())
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Edit</a>
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
    {{ $articles->links() }}
@endsection
@section('scripts')
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
            $('#pochemu_ne_rabotaet_to').submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.post('/admin/article/store', function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                })
            })
        })

    </script>
@endsection
```

Контроллер -

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

class ArticleController extends Controller
{
    public function store()
    {
//        $article = new Article($request->all());
//        Auth::user()->articles()->save($article);


        return Response::json(['msg'=>'uraaaa']);
    }
}
```

и на всякий случай роуты -

```html
<?php

Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/projects', 'ProjectsController@index')->name('projects');
Route::get('/about', 'AboutController')->name('about');
Route::group(['prefix'=>'admin'], function (){
    Auth::routes();
    Route::post('/article/store', 'Admin\ArticleController@store');
    Route::group(['middleware'=>'auth'], function () {
        Route::get('/', 'Admin\AdminController@index');
    });
});
```

Бьюсь над этой проблемой более часа. Все примеры запросов в гугле перепробовал - ничего не помогло.

Comment: Во первых. После отправки каких-либо запросов, они отображаются во вкладке `network` браузера. там можно посмотреть что возвращает сервер (запрос будет красным подсвечен) во вторых `/article/store` в префиксе внутри маршруты не начинаются с `/`, так что попробуйте указать так: `article/store`

Comment: /storage/logs/2020-03-04.log Что там пишет?

Comment: Если получаете 500 ошибку, нужно смотреть в логи. Если нет ничего в логах, скорее всего логи (не|плохо) настроены. Можно поставить явную ошибку в скрипте входа и посмотреть куда упадет сообщение об ошибке. Если никуда - добиваться чтобы где-то в очевидном месте она оказалась. Потом то-же самое с warning'ами. Когда есть логи - можно уже смотреть что случилось

Comment: Вот логи storage/logs/laravel.log [ссылка](https://pastebin.com/c6c08etY)

Comment: @tutankhamun
[logs](https://pastebin.com/c6c08etY)

Comment: Вот скрины с ошибкой - https://prnt.sc/rbdpke
Вот скрин network - https://prnt.sc/rbdq34

Comment: @AlexanderChernykh скрины конечно супер, но кликнуть то почему по `store` слову нельзя?? чтобы справа высветилась ошибка которая приходит с сервера во кладке `response`

Comment: @AlexanderChernykh но судя по логам ошибка в том что нужно `response` возвращать не так. Используйте хелпер `response()`  `response()->json([...])`

Comment: @DmitriiSedov вот

как я понял я указал не тот путь к Response... Какой нужно указать?

{message: "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::json()",…}
message: "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::json()"
exception: "Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError"
file: "C:\wamp64\www\jolyCMS\app\Http\Controllers\Admin\ArticleController.php"
line: 18
trace: [{function: "store", class: "App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ArticleController", type: "->"},…]

Comment: @AlexanderChernykh использовать хелпер а не класс. `response()->json([...])` в прошлом комменте ответил)

Comment: @DmitriiSedov спасибо вам огромное.... на душе легче стало от решения данной ошибки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ура!!!! наконец-то справился с этой проблемой!! огромное спасибо всем, а особенно @DmitriiSedov за помощь. Оказалось что я использую не верный путь к трейту Response.
Просто нужно было нажать в Network на store и прочитать ошибку.
я чуть ли не плачу ;)